# pdns - using LUA records

Tags: powerdns, round-robin

Id very much like to do [this](https://tw.saowen.com/a/35f9299d58fdbc5f47cf8ab6c823060af7162523989d082771920b9a534f23d5) but it doesn't seem to be enabled on my installation.

```
# rpm -qa | grep pdns
pdns-4.1.5-1pdns.el7.x86_64
pdns-recursor-4.1.7-1pdns.el7.x86_64
```

Ive tried both iterations in pdns.conf (**enable-lua-record** and **global-lua-record**) to the same effect:

> pdns_server[5685]: Fatal error: Trying to set unknown parameter 'enable-lua-record'

It this to be slated for v4.2? Seems to be some mixed signals out there as to whether or not it's currently available.

Also - v4.2 doesn't seem to have a release schedule. The last info I found was from 10/2017 referring to a beta. Is the current 'master' build of reasonable stability? The ultimate goal is to enable round-robin DNS and this (via LUA) seems to be the only avenue.

---

EDIT: some possibility [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/403457/powerdns-cname-with-multiple-a-records-produces-unexpected-results). I wish they had included the actual records they used.

Answer (score 1):

The config option seems to be `enable-lua-records` (note the "s").

Comment: Nice catch. I tried that and got the same error though. `Fatal error: Trying to set unknown parameter 'enable-lua-records'`

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - I did a build from **master** and was able to implement LUA records. I can already see where this feature will be v useful.